# In Linux, Can a kernel driver used by a user process corrupt the heap memory of another user process unrelated to this user process?

Tags: linux, memory, process, kernel, driver

In Linux, while a kernel driver used by a user process is using the user process's heap memory, can it corrupt the heap memory of another user process unrelated to this user process?

In other words, when a user process's heap memory is corrupted, is there a need to analyze the cause in other user processes as well?

Comment: while in kernel mode, kernel memory and the current user process are mapped. No other user processes are mapped. However, changes to kernel memory can affect other processes

Comment: It is possible for a kernel driver to corrupt anything in the system.